# Why is casting on shared_ptr like this?

Tags: c++, casting, shared-ptr

I have seen one of the old posts on the topic. Due to my new account and lack of reputation points, I cannot comment there; hence, I am making this post.

I was looking in the past for a way to cast shared pointers from one type to another (from base to derived) in order to access some private members on the derived-side. I know its best to avoid downcasting, but this was the framework... Anyway, I saw the answer on the original post was:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> ap = ...;
dynamic_cast<B&>(*ap).b_function();
if (B* bp = dynamic_cast<B*>(ap.get())
```

Now, in the command: `dynamic_cast<B&>(*ap).b_function()` I understand that the de-referencing symbol here gives us a reference to the pointed object by the shared_ptr . My question is why do we need a reference on the B (i.e. B&)? Couldn't we make it work as:

```
B& Bref = dynamic_cast<B>(*ap);
Bref.b_function();
```

I am not very familiar with templates (like shared_ptr is implemented), so I guess its my lack of knowledge on the matter. Could someone please explain to me the meaning behind the & on this context and why the alternative I gave doesn't work?

Comment: Looks like the code was not designed correctly.  Generally `dynamic_cast` is a mistake, since you should only be completing an interface, not extending it.  When you extend the interface (derived classes add new functions) you have to do this, since the parent class knows nothing about those new functions.

Comment: Sounds like you may be looking for [dynamic_pointer_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast).

Comment: The reason might not satisfy you but it's simply because that's how the standard defines it. Maybe because it's more explicit, maybe because it matches the `B*` version, maybe because it's safer (`B` is not as explicit). It's also more consistent with other casts such as `static_cast`.

Comment: You don't technically have to have the `&`, but in this case the code is casting to a reference to an instance of `B`, or: `B&`. Otherwise, you'd be making a copy of `*ap`.

Comment: What's the relationship between `A` and `B`? Does `B` derive from `A`?

Comment: You can dynamic_cast a pointer or a reference. It's impossible to dynamic_cast a value.

Comment: It might be a good idea to link to the original post that you mention several times here. You can get the link to any post on Stackoverflow by clicking on "share" below the post and copying the displayed link into your clipboard. You can then edit your question, select the text that you want to turn into the link, then clich on the chain symbol at the top of the editor (third button from the left), and paste your link from the clipboard.

Comment: @NathanOliver I was not extending the interface the way you mean it. Its from an older piece of work, so I don't remember every detail. In short, I had a hierarchy of classes. A visitor class knew the base and could implement functionality that would affect all derived classes. To do so, I was creating base type pointers that would point to derived ones. However, to retrieve the data I had to cast it. Something like that. Anyway, this 
example I posted is from another post (I do not recall who was the author). I just read something lately and had the question. Thanks for your response though

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know about that and both ways actually work. My question was focused on the 'why' is that the case.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica Yes, indeed my bad. Initially I had copied the whole post, but removed it for simplicity. Did not expect it would be relevant to some fellas. Anyway, my question was answered now. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that a cast to a non-pointer/reference type is always a *conversion* in C++. You get the converted value which is distinct from the original value. It is a new local object with its own place in memory. Consequently, any change to this copy will not affect the original value at all.

In the case of classes `A` and `B`, the cast `(B)a` would construct the new object by calling the `B::B(A&)` constructor of class `B`.

---

Of course, such conversions is not what `dynamic_cast<>` is supposed to be used for, so `dynamic_cast<>` with a non-pointer/reference type is forbidden by the standard.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I had completely forgotten that this would be the case (basically converting and creating a copy). It was still early in the morning for me. Thanks  a lot for the response.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is why do we need a reference on the `B` (i.e. `B&`)? Couldn't we make it work as:

```
B& Bref = dynamic_cast<B>(*ap);
Bref.b_function();
```

No, you cannot do this. Quoting from the C++ Stadnard [[expr.dynamic.cast/1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.dynamic.cast#1):

> The result of the expression `dynamic_­cast<T>(v)` is the result of converting the expression `v` to type `T`. **`T` shall be a pointer or reference to a complete class type, or “pointer to cv `void`”**.